# Going to Mustang Oklahoma, what is there to do? Spending money?

Tags: budget, international-travel, sightseeing, oklahoma

so I'm going to visit my friend in mustang Oklahoma, and i was trying to decide how much spending money will i need? I don't need to buy food, or hotel, just for basic activities, maybe a little shopping and if we go out to eat a couple times. Im from canada so everything is expensive about how much would i have to bring for spending money for 16 days.? and what sort of attractions are located in or near mustang oklahoma

Comment: Why bring money at all?  ATMs exist everywhere in the US, so bring your bank card and just withdraw cash as you need it.  Actually, the vast majority of expenses can be charged directly to your bank card anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Mustang is essentially a suburb of Oklahoma City, the biggest city in the state (half million in population or so).  Spending wise you will find the state to be cheaper overall compared to costs in Canada, but not by a huge amount.  I would budget based on what things cost you visiting a big city in Canada and be happy having a few dollars left at trip's end.